# How to accessing React public folder from the server folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I want to upload an image to react public folder using multer NodeJs. It was fine in development but when I deployed it, it doesn't work. It looks like the multer couldn't upload/take reference to the public folder.

this is my folder structure :

```
/client
   /public
      /img
.
.
.
/routes
   /api
      /employee.js
server.js
```

Here is what I've done :

server.js

```
// Access public folder
app.use(express.static("client/public/img"))
```

employee.js

```
// Set storage engine
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, path.join(__dirname, "../../client/public/img/profilePicture"))
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + path.extname(file.originalname))
  }
})
```

I saw the source from developer tools and it doesn't upload the file, yet it works on development.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

multer can take reference from public folder, but you need set the `endpoint` or path to upload to public folder. for example to make a folder public yo do: 
`app.use('/endpoint/to/access/public/folder', express.static(path.resolve("client/public")))`

also, your `server.js` is on your root folder as you `client` folder, so you can do something like that:

`app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'client/public')));`

Comment: according to your answer, does it looks like this in multer :
```javascript
...
destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(
      null,
      path.join(__dirname, "../../endpoint/to/access/client/public/img/profilePicture")
    )
  },
...
```

is this right?

Comment: no, with multer you use the absolute path of folder that you want to upload files.  `/endpoint/to/access/public/folder` is  to access to  your public static folder and files. for example if you have a file named `big-image.png` inside your public folder you can get this file accessing to `http://localhost:3000/endpoint/to/access/public/folder/big-image.png` because that is  the endpoint to access to your public folder. but if you want to upload files to your public folder you use the absolute path of your public folder as same way as in your employee.js

Comment: ".. but if you want to upload files to your public folder you use the absolute path of your public folder as the same way as in your employee.js"

 yes, this was the problem. I used the absolute path yet it won't be uploaded when deployed. I don't have any problem with displaying the image, but it didn't work when uploading image even though it has the success message.